# How to prevent a LogInWindow to appear in each test

Tags: c#

i'd like to ask you today, how can i skip a loginwindow while performing multiple tests.
Currently i have several tests. Each of them contains this part of code:

```
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        LogInWindow logInWindow = new LogInWindow();
        logInWindow.Visible = true;
        logInWindow.Focus();
        Application.Run(logInWindow);
```

which creates a log in window (GDPR stuff) in order assign a value to userName and password variables.

However in case of performing all tests at once, i am getting this error while compiler tries to create second login window:

SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault must be called before the first IWin32Window object is created in the application.

To be clear: i want the login window to appear only once before performing all tests at once, however it is required that if i want to start only one test it must have a login window as well.

Thank you a lot.